# Galois action of Weil restriction

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, etale-cohomology, galois-representations

Let $K/\mathbb{Q}$ be a quadratic field. Let $E$ be an elliptic curve defined over $K$ but not over $\mathbb{Q}$, and let $\bar{E}$ be the Galois conjugate of $E$. Then by the descent theory (for instance, see [section h](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/AG16.pdf)), we can construct an abelian surface $A:=Res_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(E)$, which is isomorphic to $E\times \bar{E}$ over $K$ (but not like to be over $\mathbb{Q}$).

With this setup, my question is: Knowing the $Gal(\overline{K}/K)$-action attached to the Tate module $T_{\ell}(E)$, how to compute the $Gal(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$-action attached to the Etale cohomology $H^2_{et}(A, \mathbb{Q}_{\ell})$? For instance, given a good prime $p$ of $A$ (i.e. the reduction of $A$ at $p$ is still smooth), then what is the trace of Frobenius $p$ at $H^2_{et}(A, \mathbb{Q}_{\ell})$? In particular, if there is an isogeny from $E$ to $\bar{E}$, can we understand the transcendental part of $H^2_{et}(A,\mathbb{Q}_{\ell})$ as symmetric square of $T_{\ell}(E)$?

I apolgies if the question is too complicated. Any suggestion or reference is welcome. And please feel free to add conditions if you think that is necessary for get the answer.

Comment: The Tate module of $A$ is the induced module of the Tate module for $E$.. The $H^1$ for $A$ is the dual of its Tate module, and $H^2(A)=\wedge^2 H^1(A)$.

Comment: Thanks @anon, I think you are right. It's kind of embarring that I didn't realize that the induced representation is the answer.